# Variables with underline

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting an underline in some variables on Android Studio (in this case on the 'position' variable). I think it's not an error because the application runs perfectly and the compiler passes everything ok.
I'm wondering what does that mean?

[image]

Comment: What IDE are you using? And can you post some more of the code relating to position?

Comment: @Theyna Android Studio bases on IDEA. I am using Android Studio for years, I cannot remember to have ever seen an underlined text when I was not pressing the ctrl key.

Comment: Have you checked the warning listing?

Comment: @rekire I agree with you, I just wanted to confirm that he was using Android Studio, and the edits do so.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697168/intellij-idea-underlines-variables-when-using-in-java

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I believe the underlined variables are representative of constants (final or [effectively final](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#accessing-members-of-an-enclosing-class)), because in my experience I only see this decoration when I declare a `final` object for use inside an anonymous class. I can't seem to find it in the documentation, though.

Comment: I guess you are right after reviewing some code files I see the same pattern.

Comment: Yeah that's why. Variables declared as final get the underline. Not every one tho...

Comment: For me it shows even on non-final variables. @sarigalin's answer bellow is correct, it has to do with reassigned variables.

Answer (score 47):

It could be a sign of "Reassigned parameter"

[image]

Comment: This was the case for me in IntelliJ 2018.2.1.

Comment: The main setting is under Editor -> Language Defaults -> Identifiers -> Reassigned parameters

Comment: The reassigned marker "Underscored" in Language Defaults is now also used for reassigned variables not only parameters. I made parameters now "Bold Underscored" to even distinguish it further.

Comment: Also appears for reassigned local variable.  Just turn it off if it bugs you (it bugs me--I like to build variables step-by-step, which always flags this pseudo-warning).

Answer (score 21):

I've found the answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964282).

The decoration is a syntax highlighting preference. Take a look at `File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Java/Kotlin`

In the case of Java, you can find this effect for example at `Parameters > Implicit anonymous class parameter`. It's the checkbox `Effects`.

[image]

The same with Kotlin at `Properties and Variables > Var (mutable variable, parameter or property)`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This means the variable was declared outside the current method. For example, in this case, `position` is probably declared as a class member outside the `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`, in the class where you're implementing the `onItemLongClick()` method.

They are declared like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private int position;

    // Other code...

}
```

Comment: This explains the color, but not why it is underlined.

Comment: Right, I was mistaken, it's because it's declared as `final`. Please upvote the answer by @ChrisGilardi

Comment: For what it's worth (question is pretty old), but my class is not declared as final and I still see this behavior.

Comment: In this case it means it's effectively final, hence changes to the variable outside of the onClick method will not be reflected inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

It may be because a immutable variable is subjected to modification. Like reassigning a String or trying to modify a final declared variable.

```
String buffer = "";
buffer = buffer + "new string";
```

Will underline the buffer, since string are of immutable Objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what is the [side effect in programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) then it will be easy for you. To protect your variable from the **side effect**, the IDE shows the underline as a warning to you. Which is sometimes very helpful to reduce logical bugs in your code.