# Kotlin: Why are most variables underlined in Android Studio and how do I turn that off?

Tags: android-studio, syntax-highlighting, kotlin

I wanted to know why most variables in Kotlin are underlined. Some files contain a lot of underlining which is very annoying. If I hover my mouse over a variable it doesn't give any information most of the time. But on some it says "This property has a backing field" or "Value captured in a closure". Does anybody know how to disable those underlines? Here is a screenshot with what I mean:
[image]

And realm is then underlined throughout the entire file.

Comment: Just a hint, you don't need that semicolon.

Comment: @KirillRakhman I know, but I'm used to it and do it automatically ;).

Comment: what does `Value captured in a closure` mean? I have this message in a `.filter {}` and .map {}` - the variable in those is _underlined_

Comment: @ycomp You can read about it here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#closures. It basically means that you've defined a variable outside the lambda function and using it in the lambda function.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo thanks, googling that phrase brings up nothing useful - but now with the link and your explanation it all makes sense.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It's just Editor Preferences.

**Edit:**

This is moved to

```
Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin -> Properties and Variables
```

[image]

Thanks rmirabelle for the comment

For the old plugin, you can go to

```
Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin
```

Then find `Var (mutable variable, parameter or property)` and remove Underscored effect.

I guess they just try to discourage using `var` by adding the annoying underscored. :P

[image: old plugin]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I knew that was there, but I tried changing the property with backing field. But I needed this one. This is so much better!

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo welcome! It took me sometime to find this when I started using Kotlin too.

Comment: As of Kotlin plugin 1.0.2, this setting has been moved under the `Properties and Variables` subsection

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio 3.1.2 this has been moved to -

`Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Kotlin`

[image]