# what does these under line means in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

What are warnings in kotlin and how to remove them?

[image]

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963949/kotlin-why-are-most-variables-underlined-in-android-studio-and-how-do-i-turn-th

Comment: To warn you that you might want to use a property delegate with `val` instead.

Comment: Just a suggestion you don't need so much of variables for EditText and RelativeLayout or any xml IDs you can easily access them using Kotlin Synthetic Properties.

Comment: this warring shows that these field can be private.

Comment: make them private warning will be remove.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use a private/protected modifier or change var to val because your variables is not modified. You should precise what warning you see when you move on that yellow lines. Your IDE will tell you what you should do ;)