# Underlining variables in intelliji

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some code like blow

```java
public class SimplePizzaFactory {
    public Pizza createPizza(String type) {
        Pizza pizza = null;
        if(type.equals("cheese")) {
            pizza = new CheesePizza();
        } else if(type.equals("greek")) {
            pizza = new GreekPizza();
        } else if(type.equals("pepperoni")){
            pizza = new PepperoniPizza();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return pizza;
    }
}
```

And I don't understand why underline appear with pizza variable

[image]

I have searched on google for a couple hours, but I am not sure what is the meaning of this symbol.

When I change **Pizza pizza = null;** to **Pizza pizza;**, underline disappear.

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Edit:

The purpose of question to find the reason why intellij do it like that. Maybe it is too easy, but sometime, there are many easy things we don't know.

First, I think, it is error on my code, there are some questions on my mind, like: why we don't need initilize value of varible, and what is the function of underline?

Second, As i said, I spend hours to find the answer, I have found the [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697168/intellij-idea-underlines-variables-when-using-in-java), maybe its problem like my post, but when I read all the answer, I'm still confusing, because I think, its not problem to intellij do it like, yeah, the firsh though. Maybe, it represent other things, I really know what it is. That's reason. I posted my question.

So, I hope the community understand the confuse on my mind, its simple if we have much experient with java and intellij

Anyway, Thanks to explain for me. The problem is only variable was changed on method like [@Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8681/jorn) answered

`Update`:

I want to delete this question, how can I delete it?, I read [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) many times, but I'm confused about the steps to delete it.

Comment: does it matter? It's not marked as being an error or something. This might be better to be looked for in the IntelliJ documentation, especially since we don't even know what version or build you are using. Probably because you don't need that initial assign to null. Actually, you don't even need the variable. Just replace every 'pizza = ' by 'return' and you're set

Comment: thanks, this is a example in Head First Design Pattern (Freeman), and underline is a feature of intelliji [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2018-2/#v2018-2-editor). For me, it matter.

Comment: have you read the rest of my comment? Either way, the code as written is pretty bad. being able to immediately return instead of creating a variable is the least of the issues with it

Comment: Do you get any warning or info message when you hover over that variable? Might be some code review addon/tool that thinks you shouldn't use a local variable here at all and just get rid of it and do `return new CheesePizza();` etc. pp in your switch cases.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I suggested as much as well. By the rest of his clarifications, it seems it's because the pointless initial value of null being set, since it's either overwritten, or an exception is thrown

Comment: @OH, I don't see any warning when hover over that variable. I really appreciate your solution, but the purpose of my question is about underline. I want to know, what does it represent?

Comment: I think it indicates a local variable changing value during the method.

Comment: @ManhDo what does the fact that it disappears if you remove the '= null' tell you?d
It's because you reassign a local variable: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000395439-Underlined-variables-

Comment: The link to the Intellij feature that you provided (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2018-2/#v2018-2-editor) has the explanation: _Underlining reassigned local variables and reassigned parameters_. It tells you even how you could turn off that feature.

Comment: Couple hours? Have you searched "IntelliJ variable underlined"? The very first result leads to the IntelliJ support forum which answers your question.

Comment: @QBrute, I have searched with that keyword and I have read the dicussion, but I sill confuse

Comment: @khelwood, thanks, at first, I don't think it was simple like that

Comment: @ThomasKläger, thanks, your english is not good, so I have read but I sill confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way IntelliJ renders mutable variables. Removing the `= null` initializer changes the variable to effectively `final`, so that's why the underline disappears.

Comment: Thanks, now, I got it. Maybe my question is stupid, :(